# algebraic implementation of $.when in Pacta.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, promise, algebraic-data-types

I'm writing a nodejs thing, and trying the [Pacta promise library](https://github.com/mudge/pacta) for fun. Pacta's interface is "algebraic," but I don't have any experience with that paradigm.

I'd like to know what is the "Pacta way" to accomplish the same thing as

```
$.when.apply(undefined, arrayOfThings)
.then(function onceAllThingsAreResolved(thing1Val, thing2Val, ...) {
    // code that executes once all things have been coerced to settled promises
    // and which receives ordered resolution values, either as 
    // separate args or as a single array arg
}
```

That is, given an array, an iterator function that returns a promise, and a callback function, I'd like to map the iterator onto the array and provide an array of the resolution values (or rejection reasons) to the callback once all the promises have been settled.

If there isn't an idiomatically algebraic way to express this, I'd be just as interested to know that.

EDIT: updated use of $.when to properly accommodate an array, per @Bergi.

Comment: Patca only had 4 issues ever, hasn't been touched in a year and has less than 200 downloads a month. I doubt there is a "Pacta way" :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: granted; but perhaps there is an "algebraic way" that Pacta implements support for.

Comment: The point of Pacta being algebraic is in how it works with other libraries and tools that are also algebraic - in itself there is no reason not to have a `all` method like native promises do - there is nothing less algebraic in that - Haskell's Async module for instance gladly includes methods like waitAny that operate on lists.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean `$.when(arrayOfThings)`? I assume you meant `jQuery.when.apply(null, arrayOfPromises)`

Comment: @Bergi: you're right (mostly). It is critically important that the array be able to contain some non-promise values, and that those values simply be passed along to the callback (transparently wrapping them in already-fulfilled promises if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pacta's interface is "algebraic," but I don't have any experience with that paradigm.

[ADTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) are type theory constructs that represent nested data types, like a `Promise` for `Integer`. They are heavily used in functional programming, a flavour where you always know the types of your expressions and values. There are no intransparent, implicit type coercions, but only explicit ones.

This is completely contrary to jQuery's approach, where `$.when()` and `.then()` do completely different things based on the types (and number) of its arguments. Therefore, translating your code is a bit complicated. Admittedly, Pacta doesn't have the most useful implementation, so we have to use some own helper functions to do this.

- Assume you have an array of (multiple) promises, and your `then` callback takes the arguments and returns a non-promise value:

  ```
  arrayOfPromises.reduce(function(arr, val) {
      return arr.append(val);
  }, Promise.of([])).spread(function (…args) {
      // code that executes once all promises have been fulfilled
      // and which receives the resolution values as separate args
  });
  ```
- If your callback does not take multiple arguments, use `map` instead of `spread`:

  ```
  arrayOfPromises.reduce(function(arrp, valp) {
      return arrp.append(valp);
  }, Promise.of([])).map(function (arr) {
      // code that executes once all promises have been fulfilled
      // and which receives the resolution values as an array
  });
  ```
- If your callback does return a promise, use `chain` instead of `map`:

  ```
  arrayOfPromises.reduce(function(arr, val) {
      return arr.append(val);
  }, Promise.of([])).chain(function (arr) {
      // code that executes once all promises have been fulfilled
      // and which receives the resolution values as an array
  });
  ```

  If you don't know what it returns, use `then` instead of `chain`. If you don't know what it returns and want to get multiple arguments, use `.spread(…).then(identity)`.
- If your array contains promises mixed with plain values, use the following:

  ```
  arrayOfThings.reduce(function(arrp, val) {
      var p = new Promise();
      Promise.resolve(p, val);
      return arrp.append(p);
  }, Promise.of([])).…
  ```
- If your array contains only a single or no (non-thenable) value, use

  ```
  Promise.of(arrayOfThings[0]).…
  ```
- If your array contains anything else, even `$.when` would not do what you expect.

Of course, promises that resolve with multiple values are not supported at all - use arrays instead. Also, your callback will only be called when all promises are *fulfilled*, not when they're *settled*, just as jQuery does this.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of information I was hoping for.